# How to have UNIQUE field empty?

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate

I've bar-code filed in a database table that is `UNIQUE`.
But field is not mandatory so I want to keep it empty.
I tried put `null` but it is bad idea to do.
Cause 
I'm using `Hibernate` so hibernate.hbm.xml doesn't generate wrapper class Integer that could be :

```
<property name="barcode" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="barcode" />
```

So above expression allow `null` insertion.
Instead it generate `UNIQUE` field as follow :

```
<property name="barcode" type="java.lang.Integer">
    <column name="barcode" unique="true" />
```

But I have make `barcode` in database table `UNIQUE` and `nullable`.
That don't help  anyway.

So how can I keep it empty or other way around to deal with it.

Comment: Why is `null` a bad idea?

Comment: @Furgas Cause it raise NPE while retrieve it again.

Answer (score 1):

`null` indicates the lack of data. It is perfectly reasonable to use `null` in a `UNIQUE` column as long as long as the column is not also set as `NOT NULL`.